# Is there such a thing as a hard drive with two interfaces where you can use both at once?

Tags: hard-disk

Is there any hard drive which can be controlled by two different interfaces at the same time? E.g. two USB ports, or one USB and one SATA, or one USB and one LAN/NAS?

Comment: What's your use case? Usually a HDD can only be mounted by 1 device.

Answer (score 1):

No common OS expects data on a disk to change by itself. Such a device wouldn't be considered a disk and couldn't be used just as one. It'd have horrible performance, wouldn't be safe (OS access controls can't be enforced) and wouldn't be cheap.

Try defining your use case and asking what hardware/software could do it. You may get better possibilities this way.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, contrary to common sense expectations there is such a thing: [Multipath I/O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipath_I/O) - devices with several connection routes to the system (which communicates with such a device). Such redundancy is typically a requirement of a [carrier-grade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier_grade) systems. Often the device is within a [SAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Storage_Area_Network) with [iSCSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISCSI) or [FC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibre_Channel) being used as interconnect.

Answer (score 0):

You could connect the drive to something like a raspberry pi zero and set it up as a media server. The RPi controls the drive and runs a media server allowing other devices to access it remotely even, for example, being able to use the drive as a remote drive on the other devices.